# How to set App title in Winui3 desktop app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, titlebar, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to set the app title bar with app name but it appears at the bottom of title bar.

[Title bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJi3T.png)

Instead of title as WinUI Desktop at the top, I want to have My App Title at top. Also how can I change the background colour of the title bar?

Here's my MainPage.xaml code how I'm currently setting title bar

MainPage.xaml

```
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:controlpages="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"    
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar">
           <!-- <Image Source="Images/WindowIcon.png"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Width="16" Height="16" 
                   Margin="8,0"/> -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitleTextBlock" Text="App title"
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                       Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="28,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>


        <NavigationView  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="nvSample8" 
                        PaneDisplayMode="Left"
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged8"
                        IsPaneOpen="False"
                        >
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Accounts" Icon="Contact" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Accounts" Tag="AccountsPage">
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame8" />
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            nvSample8.SelectedItem = nvSample8.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().First();
            AppTitleTextBlock.Text = "My App Title";
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it a UWP application using WinUI or a WinUI3 application? I noticed that you are doing in a `MainPage` which looks like it is a UWP app. In a WinUI3 application, it should be `MainWindow`. Or it is a page created by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set only the title instead of `WinUI Desktop` to something else, then you can do it in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file as follows

```
public MainWindow()
{
      this.InitializeComponent();
      Title = $"App name";
}
```

`Title` shows in the XAML IntelliSense for `Window`, but setting it in XAML causes an error. Set this property in code instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `Window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` to true?

You might want to check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui3

Comment: The above changes are based on above mentioned doc.
```Window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar``` is giving me an error.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @ApoorvaPetkar is it a UWP app? You are using `MainPage` not `MainWindow`.

Comment: I'm using UNO platform to create the application- https://github.com/unoplatform

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I just know UNO is cross-platform app development platform, which uses winui3 and windows community toolkit controls for development. 

Referred these links- https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vs-2022.html?tabs=windows

can you please help me understand if I'm missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ApoorvaPetkar  I don't know how UNO works but it seems to be a UWP application. I'll post an answer later about how to implement titlebar customization just from the UWP side. It works for native UWP applications and I think it should work in your project.

Answer (score 1):

@Nick's answer already shows the correct document that you need to check. But you might need to check the UWP part of it.

To change the text and the background of the Title bar, you will need to get the **CoreApplicationViewTitleBar** and set the **ExtendViewIntoTitleBar** property to `true` first. Then you could pass a UIElement you created as the TitleBar. After that, you could change the color of **System caption buttons** by getting the system title bar that holds these buttons.

MainPage.Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="AppTitleBar" Background="Red">
   
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightPaddingColumn" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" 
       Grid.Column="1"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Width="16" Height="16"
       Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitleTextBlock"
           Text="App title" 
           Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 
           Grid.Column="1"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="28,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
        // Set XAML element as a drag region.
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);

        //change color for the caption buttons
        var systemTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
        systemTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        systemTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        systemTitleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        systemTitleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    }
```